# Was Jesus a time traveller?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus

Reading online, there is a significant number of people who believe Jesus was a Christian.

To my mind that would require Jesus to travel to the future and read the new testament. Then go back in time to follow his own teachings and fulfil the events of the book.

Is that what happened?

Comment: Jesus was anointed by the Holy Spirit and is therefore titled 'Christ' meaning 'anointed'. He is the promised Messiah, again meaning 'anointed'. This title is unique to himself. No other person can bear the title, as a title. It is not correct to call Jesus a 'Christian'. He is The Christ, himself.

Comment: So if i’m following, his title is ‘Annointed’ but his religion was Judaism yeah?

Comment: Jesus Christ is the Son of God. He is Deity, himself. I do not understand your question. He was born 'King of the Jews' by birthright, received through Joseph : the husband of his mother Mary and his adoptive parent.

Comment: If people say he was Christian, they probably mean that he taught the Christian teachings, which is not surprising seeing as he is the Christ. But he wasn't a devotee.

Comment: @ClarkRadford Isrealites did not follow the ideologies of Canaan. (Except some who were idolatrous and were punished for it.) Israel believed in the God of Abraham and the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob : in God who appeared to Moses in a burning bush. [The questioning comment has disappeared but here is the answer, anyway.]

Comment: @ClarkRadford: Christ's (re)interpretation of the various teachings of Judaism drastically differed, in certain important aspects, from that of His contemporaries.

Answer (score 1):

**According to Catholicism, was Jesus a time traveller?**

The simple answer is **no**.

Jesus Christ, the Second Person of the Blessed Trinity, in his human nature was truly Our Redeemer and brought us out of sin and into a life of sanctifying grace by his death on the Cross for our salvation.

There are no Catholic teachings that state Our Lord, while in his human nature was even remotely considered a time traveller, moving back and forth in time!

There nothing to imply that he was anything in his life that could compare to [Doctor Who](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who) and his *or Black Adder with his time machine [(Back & Forth)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder:_Back_%26_Forth).

Many Christians believe that Jesus is Christian is simply due to the Fact that Jesus was the Christ and died on the Cross for our salvation. Thus Jesus is to be considered the founder of all Christendom.

In fact the ***Followers of the Way*** were first called ***Christians*** and is even mentioned in Scriptures as such. The word Christian is used three times in the New Testament: Acts 11:26, Acts 26:28, and 1 Peter 4:16.

> And when he (Barnabas) had found him (Saul or Paul of Tarsus), he brought him to Antioch. So it was that for a whole year they assembled with the church and taught a great many people.
> And the disciples were first called Christians in Antioch. - (Acts 11:26)
>
> Then Agrippa said unto Paul, Almost thou persuadest me to be a Christian. - (Acts 26:28)
>
> Yet if any man suffer as a Christian, let him not be ashamed; but let him glorify God on this behalf. - (1 Peter 4:16)

If we considered Jesus to be the foundation of Christendom, I guess that would make him a Christian, but not a time traveller.

Comment: Does that make Him a time traveller? You will never see this title in any litany whatsoever! Remember I am writing about Christ in his human nature.

Comment: @Lucian Can you point out a case in fact where Jesus in his human nature went to the future and came back in time to fulfill his mission!

Answer (score 1):

> To my mind that would require Jesus to travel to the future and read the new testament.

To your mind, yes; but, then again, you're not [Einstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein). The world-renowned physicist taught that the [space-time continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) is [relativistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity), to the point to which a hypothetical observer, situated outside of the Universe, would witness all events happening simultaneously. (This scientific idea is usually, and somewhat incorrectly, rendered into lay terms as time being an illusion, of sorts).

Now, Einstein was clearly Jewish, and it is to the Jews that God, which certainly meets the above-mentioned criteria of an objective observer, revealed both Testaments. And this supreme God was likened by the famous philosopher [Socrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) to a [Mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous), whose Thought or Reason ([Logos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos)) orders the entire Universe. Since Logos also means Word, this idea was later [picked up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo%27s_view_of_God) by both [Hellenized Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism) ([Philo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo) of Alexandria) and Christians (John the Evangelist), due to its similarity with the first chapter of the Book of Genesis, where God, through words, orders the Universe into existence.

This Mind, then, along with the Thought indwelling it, witnesses all things happening simultaneously. As such, to the extent to which Christ was truly the embodiment of the divine Logos (Logic), time travel was not needed for Him to know or read the New Testament, despite it being written decades after His time on earth.

Comment: @ClarkRadford: This is the Christian belief (which is what this site is about). Whether the faith's various statements can be objectively proven is a different question altogether, most likely meant for [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ClarkRadford: Are you referring to New Testament **claims** about Jesus possessing such divine knowledge ? If so, though they might exist, they might not be objectively verifiable; hence, they might not exactly constitute undeniable proof.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't aware that Jesus (often depicted as a corporeal being) has divine knowledge (in the sense of knowledge of the future). Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Christian was a name ***given*** in Antioch to the followers of Jesus Christ and His teachings (*Acts 11:26*). Is not a name self-imposed.

Jesus is God (*John 1:1,14*), and He live a perfect life without sins (*1 Peter 2:22*). Jesus never transgressed God's commandments (His commandments), so in that sense it could be said that He was a jew but also a Christian. There is no need to go to sci-fi to find an explanation.